# How can I call context from another class for use as a parameter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, object, datacontext

I have Class1 and Class2 for Update entity.
I create context by Update method in Class1.

```
public void Update (WRKORD wrk) {
    using (AlfaPlastikContext context = new AlfaPlastikContext ()) {
        try {
            var entity = context.Entry (wrk);
            entity.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges ();
            MessageBox.Show ("Saved");
        } catch (Exception) {
            Message.Box ("You can't enter same value!!");
        }
    }
}
```

in my Update button I wrote this code

```
Class1.Update(wrk);
Class2.Update(wl1);
```

wrk and wl1 are my objects that I created from table.

my Class2 code is

```
public void Update(WL_REQUEST uc1)
{
    var entity = context.Entry(uc1);
    entity.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Here comes `Dependency Injection` of .Net at the table. you can find this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: so what should I do can you explain a bit ? :) @RonaldHaan